# Calculate dataframe profit between pairs of string events

Tags: python, pandas

I have

```
   event   b
0  buy     4
1  nan
2  sell    5
3  buy     3
4  nan
5  nan
6  nan
7  sell    9
```

After each `buy` we have a `sell` at some unknown distance.
I need to count how many times I had a profit.

In this case, first deal earn 1 (5-4), and second deal earn 6 (9-3).

I need to produce here 2 results `total wins=2`, and `total lost=0`

So I don't care how big is the profit/lost, only how many wins/loses

Comment: Are u sure elemnt comes under sell belongs to before buy?.;..Are you sure for every buy there will sell pair exists everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop all the nans, pivot the table, then shift the sells up so they align with the buys, you will have rows of buy/sell and can then compare.

```py
df = df.dropna()
df
    event   b
0   buy     4.0
2   sell    5.0
3   buy     3.0
7   sell    9.0

df_pivoted = df.pivot(columns='event',values='b')
df_pivoted
event  buy  sell
0      4.0   NaN
2      NaN   5.0
3      3.0   NaN
7      NaN   9.0

df_pivoted['sell'] = df_pivoted['sell'].shift(-1) # shift sell values up a row
df_pivoted
event  buy  sell
0      4.0   5.0
2      NaN   NaN
3      3.0   9.0
7      NaN   NaN

df_pivoted = df_pivoted.dropna()

df_pivoted['win?'] = df_pivoted['buy'].lt(df_pivoted['sell'])
df_pivoted
event  buy  sell   win?
0      4.0   5.0  True
3      3.0   9.0  True

total_wins = len(df_pivoted[df_pivoted['win?'] == True])
total_losses = len(df_pivoted[df_pivoted['win?'] == False])
```

Comment: Thanks, why did you shift the table in 1 ? how do you know where exactly are the sell/buy going to be? I wrote in the question that this is unknown.

Comment: since we do the `df = df.dropna()`, we get rid of all rows where any column contains an na (you can use `subset=...` if you want to drop just if the na is in col 'event'). This collapses the df such that the buy and sell become in consecutive rows, so the shift will always be 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Remove un wanted columns & subract corresponding elemnts in `b` ..count total postive and negative values.

```
filter = df["b"] != ""
df = df[filter]
df['diff']=df['b'] -df['b'].shift(1)
dfs= df.iloc[1::2] 


profit = len(dfs.loc[dfs['diff'] > 0])
loss =len(dfs.loc[dfs['diff'] <0])
print(f"total wins = {profit}")
print(f"total loss = {loss}")
```

## output

```
total wins = 2
total loss = 0
```